# How to add more than 255 characters in a data validation in xlsxwriter Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am creating an excel sheet where I have to make a drop down of all the states. Code looks like below:

```
excel_file_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'template')
name = 'Template.xlsx'
excel_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'template', name)
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(excel_file)
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Details")

sheet.write("C1", "Address", style_center)
sheet.write("D1", "State", style_center)

sheet.data_validation(1, 3, 5000, 3, {'validate': 'list', 'source': ["Alabama-AL", "Alaska-AK", "Arizona-AZ", "Arkansas-AR", "California-CA", "Colorado-CO", "Connecticut-CT",
                                              "Delaware-DE", "District of Columbia-DC", "Florida-FL", "Georgia-GA", "Hawaii-HI", "Idaho-ID", "Illinois-IL", "Indiana-IN",
                                              "Iowa-IA", "Kansas-KS", "Louisiana-LA", "Maine-ME", "Maryland-MD", "Massachusetts-MA", "Michigan-MI", "Minnesota-MN", "Mississippi-MS",
                                              "Missouri-MO", "Montana-MT", "Nebraska-NE", "Nevada-NV", "New Hampshire-NH", "New Jersey-NZ", "New Mexico-NM", "New York-NY",
                                              "North Carolina-NC", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma-OK", "Oregon-OR", "Pennsylvania-PA", "Rhode Island-RI", "South Dakota-SD",
                                              "Tennessee-TN", "Texas-TX", "Utah-UT", "Vermont-VT", "Virginia-VA", "Washington-WA", "West Virginia-WV", "Wisconsin-WI", "Wyoming-WY"]})
                                              
workbook.close()
```

I am getting below error:

`UserWarning: Length of list items exceeds Excel's limit of 255, use a formula range instead`

I am not able to understand formula range. I tried to find a way to do this, in some of other articles, it says add some data in some other cells lets say E1 and add rest of the information in say E2 and the combine these cells and put it where you want it in excel.

So I tried to do it

```
sheet.write("K10", "Alabama-AL, Alaska-AK, Arizona-AZ", border_format)
sheet.write("L11", "Arkansas-AR, California-CA, Colorado-CO, Connecticut-CT", border_format)
```

I wrote some information in K10 and L11 and then tried to merge it :

```
sheet.data_validation(1, 3, 5000, 3, {'validate': 'list', 'source': '=K10&" "&L11'})
```

But it actually didn't worked and shows empty drop down.

How can I put more then 255 char values in drop down using xlsxwriter in Python

EDIT:

```
state_list = ["Alabama-AL", "Alaska-AK", "Arizona-AZ", "Arkansas-AR", "California-CA", "Colorado-CO", "Connecticut-CT",
             "Delaware-DE", "District of Columbia-DC", "Florida-FL", "Georgia-GA", "Hawaii-HI", "Idaho-ID", "Illinois-IL", "Indiana-IN",
             "Iowa-IA", "Kansas-KS", "Louisiana-LA", "Maine-ME", "Maryland-MD", "Massachusetts-MA", "Michigan-MI", "Minnesota-MN", "Mississippi-MS",
             "Missouri-MO", "Montana-MT", "Nebraska-NE", "Nevada-NV", "New Hampshire-NH", "New Jersey-NZ", "New Mexico-NM", "New York-NY",
             "North Carolina-NC", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma-OK", "Oregon-OR", "Pennsylvania-PA", "Rhode Island-RI", "South Dakota-SD",
             "Tennessee-TN", "Texas-TX", "Utah-UT", "Vermont-VT", "Virginia-VA", "Washington-WA", "West Virginia-WV", "Wisconsin-WI", "Wyoming-WY"]
             
i = 10
for state in state_list:
    sheet.write("K{}".format(i), state, border_format)
    i = i + 1

sheet.data_validation(1, 3, 5000, 3, {'validate': 'list', 'source': '=Details!K10:K61'})
```

Comment: The DV list formula is limited to 255 characters, so you can't. Add each value to a cell in a row/column then use the address of that range for the DV list formula.

Comment: @Rory I am not very good with formula's. Can you answer this questions please

Comment: Put one state in each cell (say K10:K61) then use `=Sheet1!K10:K61` as the formula.

Comment: @Rory I have added the code which I used in edit section of question. But its not reflecting the data in drop down. Can you check please

Comment: I don't speak python so not sure I can assist much further, but is the sheet actually called Sheet1?

Comment: @Rory I have updated it. Now I get an error while opening excel that "We found a problem in content of the sheet, do you want us to recover". If I click yes it removed the data validation part. Why is this error coming?

Comment: Perhaps the references need to be made absolute: `=Details!$K$10:$K$61`. I'm assuming you are using a version of Excel newer than 2007?

Comment: @Rory Its again the same issue even after using `$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to be clear, the 255 character limit on a list/string validation is an Excel limitation. XlsxWriter is just enforcing that limitation.

The workaround suggested in the Excel (and XlsxWriter) documentation is to add the validation list data to a worksheet and refer to it with a formula range like `=Details!$K$10:$K$61`.

The edited example you added in your update should work. Here it is as a working example base on it:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Details")


state_list = ["Alabama-AL", "Alaska-AK", "Arizona-AZ", "Arkansas-AR",
              "California-CA", "Colorado-CO", "Connecticut-CT",
              "Delaware-DE", "District of Columbia-DC", "Florida-FL",
              "Georgia-GA", "Hawaii-HI", "Idaho-ID", "Illinois-IL", "Indiana-IN",
              "Iowa-IA", "Kansas-KS", "Louisiana-LA", "Maine-ME", "Maryland-MD",
              "Massachusetts-MA", "Michigan-MI", "Minnesota-MN", "Mississippi-MS",
              "Missouri-MO", "Montana-MT", "Nebraska-NE", "Nevada-NV",
              "New Hampshire-NH", "New Jersey-NZ", "New Mexico-NM", "New York-NY",
              "North Carolina-NC", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma-OK",
              "Oregon-OR", "Pennsylvania-PA", "Rhode Island-RI", "South Dakota-SD",
              "Tennessee-TN", "Texas-TX", "Utah-UT", "Vermont-VT",
              "Virginia-VA", "Washington-WA", "West Virginia-WV",
              "Wisconsin-WI", "Wyoming-WY"]

worksheet.write_column('K10', state_list)
# Same as the following with row/col notation:
# worksheet.write_column(9, 10, state_list)

worksheet.data_validation(1, 3, 5000, 3,
                          {'validate': 'list',
                           'source': '=Details!$K$10:$K$61'})


workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I didnt get you. Why are you putting whole list in K10 and by the comment you mean same whole list in all rows/col?

Comment: Also in your example I have tried it but whats happening is that in D2 it has all the list of states, then in D3 it doesnt have top most state Alabama, then in D4, it doesnt have Alabama and Alaska and it continues. so at row 50, its only left with last state Wyoming-WY

Comment: *"Why are you putting whole list in K10?"* The [write_column()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-column) method can write an entire list in one go, starting from cell K10 and iterating down. It is a syntactic shortcut for writing the data in a loop.

Comment: "so at row 50, its only left with last state Wyoming-WY" I fixed that in the example. It just requires an absolute range like$K$10:$K$61 (instead of K10:K61).